# nhibernate connecting to legacy database

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am connecting to a legacy sqlserver database. One of the tables has column name "Primary". The scripts are failing due to that.

Script generated by nhibernate:
SELECT locations0_.CustomerID as CustomerID1_, locations0_.LocationID as LocationID1_, locations0_.LocationID as LocationID2_0_, locations0_.Primary as Primary2_0_,locations0_.CustomerID as CustomerID2_0_ 
FROM dbo.tblLocation locations0_ 
WHERE locations0_.CustomerID=?

Class:

```
public class Location 
{
    public virtual int LocationID { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual int? CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual string LocationName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address3 { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string StateOrProvince { get; set; }
    public virtual string PostalCode { get; set; }
       public virtual datetime? LTimeStamp{ get;set; }
    public virtual bool Primary { get; set; }
}
```

Map:
    public class TblLocationMap : ClassMap 
    {

```
    public TblLocationMap() 
    {
        Table("tblLocation");
        //LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.LocationID).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("LocationID");
                    References(x => x.Customer).Column("CustomerID");
        Map(x => x.LocationName).Column("LocationName").Length(50);
        Map(x => x.Address1).Column("Address1").Length(200);
        Map(x => x.Address2).Column("Address2").Length(200);
        Map(x => x.Address3).Column("Address3").Length(200);
        Map(x => x.City).Column("City").Length(100);
        Map(x => x.StateOrProvince).Column("StateOrProvince").Length(100);
        Map(x => x.PostalCode).Column("PostalCode").Length(20);
        //Map(x => x.Primary).Column("Primary").Not.Nullable();
        //Map(x => x.LTimestamp).Column("LTimestamp");
        HasMany(x => x.Contacts).KeyColumn("LocationID");
    }
```

sql:

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblLocation]
        (
    [LocationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NULL,
    [LocationName] nvarchar NULL,
    [Address1] nvarchar NULL,
    [Address2] nvarchar NULL,
    [Address3] nvarchar NULL,
    [City] nvarchar NULL,
    [StateOrProvince] nvarchar NULL,
    [PostalCode] nvarchar NULL,
    [Primary] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [RecTimestamp] [timestamp] NULL, 
(
    [LocationID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

GenericADOException:
could not initialize a collection: [Domain.Locations#466][SQL: SELECT locations0_.CustomerID as CustomerID1_, locations0_.LocationID as LocationID1_, locations0_.LocationID as LocationID2_0_, locations0_.LocationName as Location2_2_0_, locations0_.Address1 as Address3_2_0_, locations0_.Address2 as Address4_2_0_, locations0_.Address3 as Address5_2_0_, locations0_.City as City2_0_, locations0_.StateOrProvince as StateOrP7_2_0_, locations0_.PostalCode as PostalCode2_0_, locations0_.Primary as Primary2_0_, locations0_.CustomerID as CustomerID2_0_ FROM dbo.tblLocation locations0_ WHERE locations0_.CustomerID=?]

Inner exception:
{"Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Primary'."}

Comment: Give us more information: What errors do you get?

Comment: Add the mapping, class and actual database table to this post and we can answer your question.

Comment: Updated. I removed some columns from table. it does not work when nhibernate creates the sql script with Primary column. But works without it.

Comment: Fogot the mention. LTimestamp column is coming back as byte[] and c# is unable to convert to datetime?. Can you please help with this too?

Comment: did you disable autoquoting when configuring the sessionfactory?

Comment: nope.. using default properties..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `Primary` is a reserved word and is not getting escaped properly, therefore try implicitly escaping the column name with back ticks....

e.g.

```
Map(x => x.Primary).Column("`Primary`").Not.Nullable();
```

NHibernate will automatically swap your backtick with square braces if you are using MsSql server `[Primary]`

Strange that the schema is generating square braces but the select SQL isn't.

Comment: Hi rippo,Thanks for your reply. The Primary column needs to be in "" instead of ''. How can i do that? It did not work the sql need to be: SELECT lo_.CustomerID as CustomerID1_, lo_.LocationID as LocationID1_, 
lo_.LocationID as LocationID2_0_, lo_.LocationName as Location2_2_0_, lo_.Address1 as Address3_2_0_, 
lo_.Address2 as Address4_2_0_, lo_.Address3 as locations0_, lo_.City as City2_0_, 
lo_.StateOrProvince as StateOrP7_2_0_, lo_.PostalCode as PostalCode2_0_, lo_."Primary" as column9_2_0_, 
lo_.CustomerID as CustomerID2_0_ FROM dbo.tblLocation lo_

Comment: Did you try a back tick or a single quote? There is a difference

Comment: i used single quote.. it worked with back tick.. thanks heaps.. Do you know what can be the issue with timestamp not being converted? It is taking the data as byte array.

Comment: Glad back tick worked. Maybe you can mark this as accepted. I would ask about the `TimeStamp` in another question as asking a second question after the first question is frowned upon by certain quarters. Timestamps are mapped in a specific way see http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-timestamp  and search for 5.1.8